# Function 'doclist' has no 'filter' memberpylint(no-member)

Tags: python, django, django-views

It gives an error that Function 'doclist' has no 'filter' memberpylint(no-member)
and please give suggestion if my code is correct related to search

This Is My Model.py file

```
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250)
    types = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    desc = models.TextField()
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "documents"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my View.py File

```
def doclist(request):
    documents = Document.objects.filter()
    search_query = request.GET.get('q')

    if search_query :
        doclist = doclist.filter(
           Q(name__icontains = search_query)
        )
        print(search_query)

    return render(request, 'doclist.html', {
        'documents' : documents
    })
```

This is my Search Form

```
<form  method="GET" action="/doclist/">
        {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" class="search-txt" placeholder="Search Here" name="q" value="{{request.GET.q}}">
        <button class="search-btn" type="submit" name="action"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>

      </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the variable is `documents`, not `doclist`. `doclist` is the name of the function, it is resolved to a reference of the view function. You thus should change `doclist = doclist.filter(..)` to `documents = documents.filter(..)`:

```
def doclist(request):
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    search_query = request.GET.get('q')
    if search_query :
        documents = documents.filter(
            Q(name__icontains = search_query)
        )

    return render(request, 'doclist.html', {
        'documents' : documents
    })
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for your help means alot :)